# Wordpress Customer URL Rewrite broke after udpate

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I had a simple rewrite that seems to be broken after a WP update.

In my functions.php I have:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^design/*', '/index.php?page_id=24565', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

And in my htaccess I have:

```
RewriteRule ^^design/* //index.php?page_id=24565 [QSA,L]
```

The goal is to have an end-user load domain.com/design/123 and then the design page loads which references page id 24565 but after the page loads the 123 ID should still be attached to the URL.

Currently, if I try to load domain.com/design/123 it loads doamin.com/design and drops the 123 ID. Any suggestions? I recently updated WP to latest version and I think it broke it.

Comment: This `^^design/*` is suspicious, it should be a regex, right? `^design/.*`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just tried that and still getting the same result

Comment: Shouldn't it be `^/design/*`, by any chance?

Comment: Sounds rather wrong to me, that you are trying to set this up using _both_ `add_rewrite_rule`, and your own RewriteRule in the .htaccess. I think this should only use the former, following the setup shown in the basic example here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Basic_Usage

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the link. Even with the example I cannot get it to work. I regenerated my permalinks in WP as well with no success `add_rewrite_rule('^design/([^/]*)/?', '/index.php?page_id=24565&id=$1', 'top');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First off, you don't need that `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess` file, so just remove that line.*

And the issue with the `123` being "removed" from the URL is because that part is seen by WordPress as the page number (for paginated requests via the `<!--nextpage-->` tag or the "Page Break" block in the Gutenberg block editor), and when the page number is greater than the max number of pages, then WordPress redirects you to page #1 of that page (instead of showing a `404` error page).

So to fix the issue, just append `&page=` (or `&page=1` would also work) to the rewrite rule's query, which means we're setting the page number to `1` at all times:

```php
add_rewrite_rule( '^design(?:/\d+|)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=24565&page=', 'top' );
```

And this isn't required, but I changed the RegEx pattern (the *first* parameter above) so that it matches `example.com/design` and `example.com/design/<number>` *only*. If you don't like that, then just use your existing RegEx pattern (`^design/*`).

So I hope that helps, and remember to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings admin page, without having to make any changes.

Comment: Wow that did it. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped! But um, can I also get an upvote from you? :)